# Replicating Charter BT of mathdesign using unicodemath

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, mathdesign

I'm trying to replicate the `\usepackage[charter-bitstream]{mathdesign}` look using `unicode-math`.

Unfortunately, using the `mathdesign` package breaks the text font, i.e., bold text in headlines is not bold anymore etc. on TexLive 2019 using LuaTex.

Since the text font used in our documents is Charter, I want a math font that properly matches the look. However, `mathdesign` does not document which fonts it uses to replace the math symbols missing in Charter.

So far, I have the following:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\unimathsetup{math-style=TeX,partial=upright,nabla=upright}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{latin,Latin}]{XCharter-Roman}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{latin,Latin}]{XCharter-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=it/{latin,Latin}]{XCharter-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfit/{latin,Latin}]{XCharter-BoldItalic}
```

Does anyone know fitting substitutes for the other fonts used by mathdesign?
E.g., the greek symbol font?
The main problem is that Libertinus `\nu` looks too similar to the Charter v.
I'm leaning a bit towards using GFS Didot for the greek symbols but maybe someone knows a better fit or has any recommendations what else to replace to replicate the look of `mathdesign` better.

Comment: what do you mean by "mathdesign breaks the text font"? Do you load it before fontspec?

Comment: The font stays the same but everything that should be bold like paragraph, section or chapter headers is not bold anymore. I'm not loading fontspec at all but I think the document class I'm using loads it.

Comment: well loading it after fontspec (or not using fontspec at all) is not good. You should better try to make a complete example, font setup isn't easy anyway and it gets difficult if one has guess the unknown behaviour of an unknowns class.

Comment: I've verified that the class loads fontspec. The class is on github and should be in the TexLive package repos, hence, I can try to create a small example.
However, `mathdesign` uses T1 by default and as far as I understood it, it is recommended to switch to Unicode compatible fonts in new documents. So, I'm not sure if it makes more sense to try to get `mathdesign` to run or just use `unicode-math` which works fine.

Comment: Sure unicode-math is more sensible. But imho not if you then start to replace all sort of symbols by text chars - you are then loosing the correct unicode mappings. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487319/2388.

Comment: Not sure if I understand that correctly because I'm not trying to replace symbols by text chars but rather I want to use different fonts for different symbols because the font I want to use does not support all symbols.
Anyways, thanks already for the hint with loading it after `fontspec`. If I modify the class to load it before loading `fontspec` it works fine with `mathdesign`. Not sure if a port to `unicode-math` might be a better solution, though.

Comment: You want to replace the symbols by chars from text fonts. A `a` in a italic text font has a different unicode value than e.g. the mathematical italic `a`.