# Is there a Mathspec equivalent for LuaLaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, mathspec

Wondering what are the use cases of `unicode-math` and `mathspec` packages, I stumbled upon [this excellent question and better answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/what-is-the-difference-between-unicode-math-and-mathspec), that helped me clarify the situation.

If I understand correctly, the goal of the `mathspec` package is to be able to use regular (unicode?) fonts to typesetting math. This may not be the ideal situation, but makes perfect sense in some cases.

Unfortunately, it seems that the `mathspec` package is only compatible with `XeLaTeX` and its maintenance status is unclear.

Im aware of the `mathastext` package, but its author says, that it:

> was initially developed for the traditional TEX fonts and engines, and that compatibility with Unicode engines and OpenType fonts is partial.

So I wonder how authors have to proceed if they are using `LuaLaTeX` and want to use non-math regular fonts to typeset their formulae? Is there any mathspec-equivalent for `LuaLateX`? Does this make any sense at all?

Comment: if you care about accessibility and copy&paste use unicode-math. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487319/2388

Comment: use unicode-math you just need one math font to set up the math mode parameters, you can additionally load any number of opentype text fonts for `\mathxxx{...`

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any `mathspec`-equivalent for LuaLaTeX?

I suggest you look into the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package. It works with both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

(transferred from comment)
[`mathfont`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathfont) works both with xelatex and lualatex.