mathastext missing characters
I am using mathastext package (and lualatex or xelatex) but it misses to use some characters from my personal font.
My code is just using:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{my_font.ttf}
\usepackage[italic,LGRgreek,noendash]{mathastext}
\begin{document}

$\Theta \theta$

\end{document}

Most characters are correctly used but for example \theta and \Delta are incorrect. In the case of Theta, it uses something similar tu \vartheta just because of using "mathastext".
If you comment lines of fontspec and setmainfont it still does this.
I have tried with unicode characters U+03B8, U+0398, U+03D1, U+03F4 and none of them seem to subtitute it.
With Delta, and presumably others, I have a similar problem.
How can i get rid of this character and replace it with mine?
Kind regards!
Edit: All math greek letters aren't being used.

Welcome! mathastext can take Greek characters only from 'TeX fonts'. It can't use an opentype font for both Latin and Greek. (Page 37 of the manual.) It is not recommended for use with Unicode engines. (Again, this is from the package's own documentation.) Page 37 suggests various alternatives.

@cfr I updated my installation today and there is a new version of mathastext.  There is a section on Unicode engines on page 16 which probably is your page 37...

@user691586 Ah, yes. Thanks for the updated reference. The content seems to be the same and only the location of that section has changed.

@cfr thanks for confirmation, I did not know how to get hold of the earlier version of the doc...

thanks for the interest. I found the experimental package mathspec which does the job.
A small drawback is that it forces to use XeLatex, no LuaLatex, which I didn't want but still love it.
Hope it helped.

perhaps you will be interested by mathfont  which works with lualatex as well.

I would use unicode-math, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487319/2388 why.

yes, mathfont also works very well! and works better with lualatex.
Thanks!
For unicode-math I think the limitations comes from the font you are using. Mine does not include many characters, and for math I don't know what characters it uses. Doesn't work for my case. Thanks also anyway!
